# Can we define the effective mass or the moving mass of a photon?

Tags: general-relativity, mass, mass-energy

I know that the rest mass of a photon is zero. but the photon can be bent by gravity (which can also be explained by the curvature of space-time due to the effect of mass), this implies that it must have some effective mass, while in motion, therefore does it also bend space-time? can the mass of the photon be defined in common(SI) units, how?

Comment: Use $E = m_{rel}c^2$. Or not, because the concept of relativistic mass is of dubious value.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I did not quite understand your comment, can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The concept of [relativistic mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity#Relativistic_mass) is obsolete. We do not need to ascribe mass to a photon in order to see that it distorts space:

As an excitation of the electromagnetic field, a photon contributes to the [stress-energy tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#In_general_relativity_2) $T_{\mu\nu}$, which, through the [Einstein field equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations), will distort the metric on spacetime, and thus exert gravity.