# Does light have mass? Why?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, photons, mass, mass-energy

I've been wondering whether light has mass. Yet given the wave-particle duality of light, the statement seems to be affirmative. With that, how to calculate it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we define the effective mass or the moving mass of a photon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/143641/can-we-define-the-effective-mass-or-the-moving-mass-of-a-photon) or answer already therein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In quantum field theory, a photon's **rest** mass is proven to be zero. But relativistically, the photon's energy leads to the **relativistic** mass $m=\frac{h\nu}{c^2}$.

Related link: http://www.desy.de/user/projects/Physics/Relativity/SR/light_mass.html

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid mass concept of photon at all, because it doesn't have *rest* mass. Relativistic mass is very slippery thing and is not unambiguously defined. Someone just put Lorentz factor $$ {\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-{\frac {v^{2}}{c^{2}}}}}} $$ besides **rest mass** (multiply by $m_0$) and has called it "relativistic mass". Now we know for sure that photon has NO rest mass, so you can't substitute something for $m_0$ in photon case. Thus **photon doesn't have relativistic mass** too !

However, it has momentum:
$$p = mc$$
using Einstein famous relation between mass and energy $E=mc^2$ and photon energy $E=h\nu $, we get momentum as:
$$ p = \frac{h\nu}{c} $$

Still a bit strange that some object *without a rest mass* can have momentum, but it is so !
There are numerous experiments which proves [light pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pressure). To me photon and fields in general are very strange things.