# Photon effective mass in plasma

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, mass, quantum-electrodynamics, plasma-physics

How can we compute the effective mass of the photon in a plasma in QED? I assume there must be a way of computing it from QED Lagrangian.

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/143641/59023

Answer (score 3):

Light wave in plasma obeys [the dispersion relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waves_in_plasmas)
$$\omega^2=\omega_p^2+k^2c^2,$$
where $\omega_p$ is the plasma frequency.
Multiplying this equation by $\hbar$ we have
$$\hbar^2\omega^2=\hbar^2\omega_p^2+\hbar^2k^2c^2
\leftrightarrow E^2=m^2c^4+p^2c^2.$$
We now readily identify
$$
m^2c^4=\hbar^2\omega_p^2\Rightarrow m=\frac{\hbar\omega_p}{c^2}.$$

Sanity check: [here is a link that comes up in google](http://users.sussex.ac.uk/%7Ewaa22/rp/Plamsa_frequency_and_Photon_Mass.html) where similar derivation is done.